# Drush core files location

Tags: drush

I don't want to add some commands I don't want to know where drush configuration file is I am simply looking for a file which contains drush command functions.

I am running drush on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands are in a folder called 'commands' in the root of the Drush folder.

If you don't know where that folder is on your machine, running `locate drush.php` in terminal should help you find it pretty quickly.

In fact, running `locate drush/commands` should give you a list of all the individual include files related to commands, but it depends if your Drush files live in a folder with that name.